# Charts losing their axis values on table rendering

Tags: charts, birt

When using a table to render a chart, I get a strange behaviour in the axis values.

Here's how it happens:

- Value A, the chart is complete (trend, axis, axis values),
- Value B, this message is shown: "this chart contains no data",
- Value C, the chart is incomplete (trend OK, axis OK, no axis values are shown)

I end up with reports being inconsistent due to the lack of information.

I was able to circumvent the issue by hiding the chart instead of showing a message. However, I'd really prefer to show the "this chart has no data" message.

Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: I was able to circumvent the issue by hiding the chart instead of showing a message. However, I'd really prefer to show the "this chart has no data" message.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was put a textobject on the report with a "No data" message and then "Suppress" the textbox according to the following formula:

```
not(IsNull(Count(_Some_seriesname_))) and not(Count(_Some_seriesName_) = 0)
```

where `_Some_seriesname_` was the field we used in our chart.